# Excesso de símbolo % dentro do LIKE

Tags: postgresql, genexus

Temos um sistema em GX EV3 u2 gerando Java e conectando em banco Postgresql 9.3. No geral a performance é aceitável, mas em determinados momentos temos gargalos e percebi que acontecem justamente quando é executada alguma query com LIKE.

Olhando mais à fundo, descobri que o problema é quando o GX gera código para instrução com LIKE, ele preenche o tamanho do campo com caracteres % e então o Postgres acaba gerando um plano de execução ruim para a consulta. Se tirar (manualmente) o excesso de %, a consulta fica rápida.

Ex: num campo de busca de endereço; "endereco varchar(120)", o código gerado pra uma busca vira algo como

```
select endereco from cliente where endereco like 'rua do brasil%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'
```

Uma query dessas executa em 1.35 segundos, porém retirando o excesso de %, deixando somente 1, a mesma query roda em 0.33 seg.

Como posso resolver esse problema? O que pode/deve ser feito para contornar ou solucionar isso de vez? Seria um bug do GX ou a forma que está sendo programado é que deve ser melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Quando se tem um LIKE esta-se completando o string con '%' ao final porque em versões anteriores de GX se requeria sempre completar os strings com brancos, e para evitar que a condição seja invalida, neste caso se completa com '%'.  Isso já não é necessário nas novas versões de GeneXus.

Se bem o assunto estava reportado no [SAC #31034](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,31034), até agora não se tinha reportado problema algum com esse comportamento. O SAC foi ativado novamente para corregi-lo nos próximos upgrades.